# How to plot these functions? (Utility functions)

Tags: graphing-functions, economics, utility

These functions are from my Microeconomics course. I don't know how to plot them (I haven't studied this topic in my Maths courses), so it would be really grateful if you can give me some help:

$$
\ U(x_1,x_2 )=x_1+min\{x_1,x_2\}
$$

and this one:
  $$
\ U(x_1,x_2 )=max\{min\{x_1,4x_2\}, min\{4x_1,x_2\}\}
$$

If you know some book that explains this topic, please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint for the first one: Consider the $(x_1, x_2)$ plane and look at the line $x_1=x_2$ line. On one side of that line, $x_1 < x_2$ (so $min(x_1, x_2) = x_1$ there). On the other, $x_1 > x_2$ (so $min(x_1, x_2) = x_2$ there). So we have two different expressions for $U$ over the two regions. What do they represent geometrically? For the second problem, we have more regions to consider, but the idea is the same.

Comment: I will try it. Thank you!